# C# WPF Binary Reading

Tags: c#, wpf

Alright, so I basically want to read any file with a specific extension. Going through all the bytes and reading the file is basically easy, but what about getting the type of the next byte? For example:

```
while ((int)reader.BaseStream.Position != RecordSize * RecordsCount)
{
// How do I check what type is the next byte gonna be?
// Example:
// In every file, the first byte is always a uint:
uint id = reader.GetUInt32();
// However, now I need to check for the next byte's type:
// How do I check the next byte's type?
}
```

Comment: Terminology: writing such a file is called serialization; reading, deserialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bytes don't have a type. When data in some language type, such as a char or string or Long is converted to bytes and written to a file, there is no strict way to tell what the type was : all bytes look alike, a number from 0-255.

In order to know, and to convert back from bytes to structured language types, you need to know the format that the file was written in.

For example, you might know that the file was written as an ascii text file, and hence every byte represents one ascii character.

Or you might know that your file was written with the format {uint}{50 byte string}{linefeed}, where the first 2 bytes represent a uint, the next 50 a string, followed by a linefeed.

Because all bytes look the same, if you don't know the file format you can't read the file in a semantically correct way. For example, I might send you a file I created by writing out some ascii text, but I might tell you that the file is full of 2-byte uints. You would write a program to read those bytes as 2-byte uints and it would work : any 2 bytes can be interpreted as a uint. I could tell someone else that the same file was composed of 4-byte longs, and they could read it as 4-byte longs : any 4 bytes can be interpreted as a long. I could tell someone else the file was a 2 byte uint followed by 6 ascii characters. And so on.

Many types of files will have a defined format : for example, a Windows executable, or a Linux ELF binary.

You might be able to guess the types of the bytes in the file if you know something about the reason the file exists. But somehow you have to know, and then you interpret those bytes according to the file format description.

You might think "I'll write the bytes with a token describing them, so the reading program can know what each byte means". For example, a byte with a '1' might mean the next 2 bytes represent a uint, a byte with a '2' might mean the following byte tells the length of a string, and the bytes after that are the string, and so on. Sure, you can do that. But (a) the reading program still needs to understand that convention, so everything I said above is true (it's turtles all the way down), (b) that approach uses a lot of space to describe the file, and (c) The reading program needs to know how to interpret a dynamically described file, which is only useful in certain circumstances and probably means there is a meta-meta format describing what the embedded meta-format means.

Long story short, all bytes look the same, and a reading program has to be told what those bytes represent before it can use them meaningfully.